# ActiveMQ 5.7.0 compilation failure

Tags: java, activemq-classic

This statement fails to compile as `getUserGroups` returns a `Map<String, Set<Principal>>`.

```
Map<String, Set<GroupPrincipal>> usergroups = ((SimpleAuthenticationPlugin) plugin).getUserGroups();
```

Can any one please help here.

Note: The same code works with ActiveMQ 5.2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code changed almost a *decade* ago via [this commit](https://github.com/apache/activemq/commit/3dbc9c9548118f4a580c0a5da477543b6aae6a9a#diff-ecf8bcc4887e90751462877d83192c9593977134a003baceaafb9ede1765d46bL65). It was related to [AMQ-3322](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-3322). The Jira doesn't have a particularly clear explanation of why the change was made. It simply says:

> Genrify [sic] code to improve compile time safety.

I recommend you update your plugin and your broker to the [latest version](http://activemq.apache.org/components/classic/download/). Even 5.7.0 is quite old at this point.

Comment: Thank you very much for the info.

Answer (score 0):

Are you tied to an older JDK version? That would be the only reason to stay on 5.7.0. Otherwise, as @justin indicated you should upgrade.

If you must stay on the v5.7.0 version, then you must patch the 5.7.0 code base to change the return types to match. The 'middle' version number change (ie 5.2.x -> 5.7.x) allows for these types of internal-API, non-client facing changes to method signatures.

Comment: so I had old JDK and and 5.2 AMQ. But now upgrading to Azul JDK 1.8.
by "you must patch the 5.7.0 code base", do you mean local build of 5.7.0 with return type change ( its not an option for me, as need to consume library from organization's maven repo ) ?

Comment: What version of the ActiveMQ broker are you required to deploy this plugin? Is upgraded to latest 5.15.x or 5.16.x an option?